# Recover files overwritten by generated code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework

I have a Winforms project that had a amongst others, 7 forms that I blindly named them with the same name that I named tables in my SQL server. Now I was trying to experiment with Entity Frameworks Data Model and visual studio generated classes for the tables in Database. For these 7 forms that class names were identical visual studio deleted all the code that I had in the forms. Is there any way to recover my old code.
I have no usable backup!

Comment: Hopefully next time you use some kind of version control system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry to say, but unless you have any backup there is no way to recover that files directly.

You could use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) (or one of the other options in [this blog article](http://blog.wibeck.org/2013/02/free-options-for-reflector-net-decompiler/)) to disassemble the assembly you have once compiled. You will have at least something like what you had. (You will lose comments and other stuff)

Maybe slightly off-topic, but when you are lucky, you might find your files back with some disk recovery tools like GetDataBack from the company Runtime. I use it a lot myself.

Comment: any free decompilers? I do have working compiled with debugging executables

Comment: If you have the compiled executables then recovering the source should not be a problem.

Comment: I didnt find anything with disk recovery... now I'm trying decompilers... don't .pdb files contain code?

Comment: k, thanks for all your help... i'm going to get it in the end... last resource a few nights to rewrite code....

Comment: Decompiler was a great idea.  Needed a bit of cleanup but at least the code was there.  Thanks!!!!